# Issue with Naive Bootstrapping (US Government Bonds)

Tags: fixed-income, python

I am using the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_curve#Construction_of_the_full_yield_curve_from_market_data) to determine the discount factor function. I get the data for Coupons, Face Values and Closing Prices from Thomson Reuters, which I insert into the Dataframe `df`. However, I am getting that `dicount_factors` contains negative values as a result of the inverse of `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues`. **I am trying to decipher if there is a flaw in my code below**.

```
df:

   months_to_maturity                      orig_iss_dt  \
1                   6                    2015-06-25 00:00:00.0   
2                  12                    2015-06-25 00:00:00.0   
3                  18                    2015-06-30 00:00:00.0   
4                  24                    2015-06-15 00:00:00.0   
5                  30                    2015-06-30 00:00:00.0   

             maturity_dt  pay_freq_cd  coupon  closing_price  FACE_VALUE  
1  2015-12-24 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000      99.960889         100  
2  2016-06-23 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000      99.741444         100  
3  2017-06-30 00:00:00.0            2   0.625      99.968750         100  
4  2018-06-15 00:00:00.0            2   1.125     100.390625         100  
5  2020-06-30 00:00:00.0            2   1.625      99.984375         100
```

The code:

```
#Determining the dimensions of the matrix of coupons and face values
#pay_freq_cd is number of coupon payments per year
max_freq_payments = df['pay_freq_cd'].max()
no_of_months_between_payments_for_matrix = 12/max_freq_payments
number_of_columns_and_rows = df['months_to_maturity'].max()/no_of_months_between_payments_for_matrix

df['FACE_VALUE'] = 100
df = df.sort(['months_to_maturity'], ascending=[True])
df = df.reset_index()

for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
    no_of_coupons_per_year_2 = row['pay_freq_cd']
    no_of_months_between_payments_2 = 12/no_of_coupons_per_year_2               
    if math.isnan(no_of_months_between_payments_2):

        matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,(row.months_to_maturity/no_of_months_between_payments_for_matrix)-1] = (row['FACE_VALUE']) 
    else:
        matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,0:((row.months_to_maturity/no_of_months_between_payments_2)-1)] = row['coupon']
        matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,(row.months_to_maturity/no_of_months_between_payments_2)-1] = (row['FACE_VALUE']) + row['coupon']

price_array = df['closing_price'].values
price_array = np.where(np.isnan(price_array), 100, price_array)
inv_matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues = inv(matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues)
dicount_factors = np.dot(inv_matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues, price_array)
```

**Edit**: I am not accounting for $epsilon$ , as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_curve#Construction_of_the_full_yield_curve_from_market_data), in the equation $AP = F + epsilon$ and can hence directly solve $AP = F$ as a system of Equations. **However, I am wondering could this be where my problem stems from?**

Thank You